# Using Winnovative in SharePoint workflow

Tags: sharepoint-2010, html2pdf, winnovative

Hopefully someone can tell me what I am doing wrong here. I have a SharePoint 2010 workflow I am coding in Visual Studio, and I was trying to emulate what is being done [here](http://blog.philwicklund.com/fff/2009/03/programmatically-convert-an-infopath-form-into-a-pdf.html), but as soon as I hit this line:

```
PdfConverter pdfConverter = new PdfConverter();
```

My workflow errors out.

I have Phil's book (workflow's in action) which contains an old version of the winnovative dll in one of his code samples, and thinking that might be the issue, I downloaded the newest version from winnovative's site, updated the using line at the top from:

```
using Winnovative.WnvHtmlConvert;
```

to simply:

```
using Winnovative;
```

as per the developer documentation that came with this newer version, and still no luck. Is there something else I need to do that I'm missing when using this with SharePoint? When utilizing an XSL style sheet for some transforms I had to deploy the xsl to the templates via my project utilizing the sharepoint mapped folder from within Visual Studio. Is something similar required for the winnovative dll to be utilized as well, so that the functions within the dll can be accessed?  Do I need to do regsvr32 on the sharepoint server to utilize (something that literally just occurred to me as I'm writing this post), or is adding the reference in visual studio and compiling my code enough? Sorry, not the world's greatest developer, so some insight would be HUGELY appreciated. Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Following the breadcrumbs of my questions, I found out the dll needed to be deployed to the GAC. Once I did that it worked. This has been a big learning experience, but at least now I know. Thanks for looking.